# Is there a constant time algorithm for generating hilbert points curve incrementally?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, hilbert-curve

The [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) on the Hilbert Cube includes functions that encode/decode arbitrary indices to/from arbitrary points on the Hilbert Curve. Those algorithms aren't constant-time. Is there a constant-time algorithm that, given an actual point on the curve (and, perhaps, some required state), generates the next point (and the next state)?

Formally, I want a type `State`, and a tuple `(initialState, nextState) :: (State, State -> ((Nat, Nat), State)`, such that each application of `nextState` gives us the next point of the Hilbert curve, and such that that `nextState` is optimal, which is probably not the case for the algorithm presented on Wikipedia, since it possibly misses the opportunity for incremental computation that we have here. Illustration:

```
data State = _

initialState :: State
initialState = _

-- This must be optimal
nextState :: State -> ((Nat, Nat), State)
nextState = _

-- Returns the `nth point` of the hilbert curve
hilbertPoint :: Nat -> (Nat, Nat)
hilbertPoint n = iterate (snd.nextState) initialState !! n
```

Comment: When you say "generating points on the fly," do you mean "generating random points on the Hilbert curve," or something else?

Comment: @templatetypedef maybe I was ambiguous, so I've added layers of redundancy on the question to make it as specific as possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the next point on the curve?" The curve is continuous.

Comment: @templatetypedef the Wikipedia article has a function, `d2xy : Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)` to convert integers to 2D points on the hilbert curve in a square divided into `n by n` cells. `map (d2xy n) [0..]` is the list of points I want to generate incrementally.

Comment: @Gene why did you delete your answer? I found it very useful.

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with Haskell. I know little of that language.  But I'll undelete since you asked...

Comment: If you are interested in being able to generate the n-th point along the curve directly, have a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/galtay/hilbert_curve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "Is there an algorithm for generating the vertices of a Hilbert curve in sequence with O(1) cost per vertex?" the answer is yes. This is a standard exercise in recursion. If you have the usual turtle graphics primitives for emitting the vertices, it looks like this:

```
-- Angle must be + or - 90.0 degrees.
procedure Hilbert(Order : in Natural;
                  Angle : in Float) is
   Step : constant Float := 1.0; -- length of base case edge
begin
   if Order > 0 then
      Turn(Angle);
      Hilbert(Order - 1, -Angle);
      Walk(Step);
      Turn(-Angle);
      Hilbert(Order - 1,  Angle);
      Walk(Step);
      Hilbert(Order - 1,  Angle);
      Turn(-Angle);
      Walk(Step);
      Hilbert(Order - 1, -Angle);
      Turn(Angle);
   end if;
end Hilbert;
```

Initiate the recursion with

```
Hilbert(7, 90.0);
```

to get a 7th order curve.

**Addition**

Since you seem to be interested in an iterator pattern, you can either use the logic above and a language (like Python or Ruby) with generators, or you can implement the generator yourself with the usual techniques for recursive to iterative code conversion.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting the answer. I only added the Haskell flag because it is the language on which I was comfortable to express the problem precisely. I ported your answer [to JavaScript](http://lpaste.net/181204) and turns out, as I suspected, it is about 4 times faster than [the Wikipedia version](http://lpaste.net/181205) when you absolutely must generate all points (which is my case). Thank you.